# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable with discord API and youtube_dl

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl

i am making a discord music bot with a lot of other features and i am getting this error all the time

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
  channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
  connect = await channel.connect()
  await connect(channel)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, url):
  voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client
  server = ctx.message.guild
  voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client(server)
  player = await  voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url)
  players[server.id] = player
  player.start()
```

this is the log line/terminal:

```
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 55, in play
    voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client(server)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Can somebody help me with this thx.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call [`guild.voice_client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voice_client#discord.Guild.voice_client) which is a property, not a method from what I can see in the docs.

You are getting a `'NoneType' object is not callable` error because your guild object does not have a VoiceClient associated with it.

If you look at the docs for [`VoiceClient`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voice_client#discord.VoiceClient) it looks like you retrieve one via [`VoiceChannel.connect()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voice_client#discord.VoiceChannel.connect)